# node programmatically require express routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am new to node which I am now using extensively with firebase functions.  I found this wonderful piece of code [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/170):

```
    const app = express();
    const main = express();
    main.use('/', app);
    main.use(bodyParser.json());
    main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    }));
    exports.webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);
    const glob = require("glob");
    const files = glob.sync('./**/*.function.js', {
      cwd: __dirname,
      ignore: './node_modules/**'
    });
    for (let f = 0, fl = files.length; f < fl; f++) {
      const file = files[f];
      const functionName = file.split('/').pop().slice(0, -12); // Strip off '.function.js'
      if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
        exports[functionName] = require(file);
      }
    }
```

This combs through the file stack in functions/filename/etc.f.js and pulls out my export functions which all end in f.js.  Works great.  Now I have repurposed this to also try and pull in a similar file stack for api routes and it now looks like this

```
    const app = express();
    const main = express();
    main.use('/', app);
    main.use(bodyParser.json());
    main.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false
    }));
    exports.webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);
    const glob = require("glob");
    const camelCase = require("camelcase");
    const files = glob.sync('./**/*.js', {
      cwd: __dirname,
      ignore: ['./node_modules/**', './index.js']
    });
    for (let f = 0, fl = files.length; f < fl; f++) {
      const file = files[f];
      const pathCheck = file.slice(-6, -3);
      if (pathCheck === 'api') {
        const path = file.slice(1, -7); // Strip off '.api.js'
        app.use(`${path}`, require(file));
      } else {
        const functionName = camelCase(file.slice(0, -5).split('/').join('_')); // Strip off '.f.js'
        if (!process.env.FUNCTION_NAME || process.env.FUNCTION_NAME === functionName) {
          exports[functionName] = require(file);
        }
      }
    }
```

The file structure for my api stack as follows

```
    functions
    ---api
    ------v1
    --------deposit.api.js
    --------invoice.api.js
    ------v2
    --------deposit.api.js
    --------deposit
    ------------:depistId (file name)
    -----------------transaction.api.js
    ---db
    ------deposit
    ------------onCreate.f.js
    ------------onUpdate.f.js
```

Expected paths would be

```
    /api/v1/deposit
    /api/v1/invoice
    /api/v2/deposit
    /api/v2/deposit/:deposit/transaction
```

In each of my filename.api.js I have something to the affect of

```
    var express = require('express')
    var router = express.Router()

    // middleware that is specific to this router
    router.use(function timeLog(req, res, next) {
      console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
      next()
    });

    router.delete('/:depositId', (req, res) => {
      // firebaseHelper.firestore
      //     .deleteDocument(db, contactsCollection, req.params.contactId);
      return res.status(200).send('Deposit deleted');
    });

    module.exports = router
```

It just doesn't seem to work.  If I manually add the path and require the file in index.js, it works fine.  Wondering if there is something wrong with my code, or understanding of how node works, appreciate any help.

Woohoo for first question!,

Thanks in advance,

Chad

Comment: Is the relative file `path` correct for where the `require()` call is? Also, could you provide more information than "it just doesn't seem to work" - error messages, undefined behavior, steps to reproduce, etc.

Comment: wow, not how I wished my first question would go.  Took awhile for me to figure out how to trouble shoot a deploy to firebase, but I had to adjust the slice to remove a leading "." and remove a "/" from the path.  Should have done more before posting.